# ArcGIS Javascript 4.x add state boundary with feature layer

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

How to set the the following service api to the state boundary on the map.

https://esri.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=045485554d804e47b7972e49adacb4b8

Because I call the service url in the angular but the map keep showing the country boundary instead of the state boundary. Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

This is what I trying to do

[image]

This is what I get

[image]

This is the code:
[image]

I guess it is something related to the layers attribute in the picture below, I just don't know how to choose the attribute there:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature service has three layers.  You can specify which one to use in the "url" parameter. If you don't point to a specific one, it will default to the first one - which in this case is the "country" layer - "0".

In the URL to the FeatureLayer, change the ending from `FeatureLayer` to `FeatureLayer/1` to display the Malaysia Negeri Boundaries.

You'll probably also want to set the transparency on that layer and/or change the default renderer that layer has.

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=b7fda90324624e3b971fe98810be4091

Comment: Ok,i get it already. Just to make it more clear on here. You can add an attribute `layerId` that is under the `FeatureLayer` constructor to declare which layer you actually want in your scenario.

Comment: Yes @kiku, you can either specify it in the `layerId` property OR as part of the URL.  Doing it in the URL is more backward compatible with older API version. Either way will work.

Comment: by the way, you did mention that also can change the default renderer. Do you have the link to the documentation about the renderer because I couldn't find the documentation @Bjorn

Comment: @kiku - you might find these useful starts:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/visualization/
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/style-a-feature-layer/